# List Sorted incorrectly

Tags: c#, list, sorting

i have following code

```
List<TimeZoneInfo> timeZoneList = new List<TimeZoneInfo>(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones());
timeZoneList.Sort((item1, item2) => { return string.Compare(item2.Id, item1.Id); });
```

but it does not sort the list correctly. (using linq.OrderBy() yields same result).
but the following code sorts correctly.

```
List<string> timeZoneList1 = new List<string>();
foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
            timeZoneList1.Add(timeZoneInfo.Id);
timeZoneList1.Sort((item1, item2) => { return string.Compare(item1, item2); });
```

what is the problem? what do i missing?

really?
no one knows the answer?

--------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------
where as i assign the list to a Combobox, it will appears in the wrong order but it will be fixed when i set the DisplayMember of the Combobox. can any one explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You have swapped the order of item1 and item2 in your comparison functions.

Comment: i don't thing so. please add the code and see the result. so what`s the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you have the following line:

```
timeZoneList.Sort((item1, item2) => { return string.Compare(item2.Id, item1.Id); });
```

Should this not be:

```
timeZoneList.Sort((item1, item2) => { return string.Compare(item1.Id, item2.Id); });
```

You have the item IDs in the `string.Compare` method the wrong way around in your first example. In your second example they're the correct way around, which is why that sorts correctly.

Comment: at least it should orders the list reversed, mean while it orders the list completely hashed. (please read the edited question)